# Can't import C++ code, written in VS 2015 in Win32 with StaticLibrary dll, that takes keyboard input in masm as .lib and .dll file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, masm

I have written the following code in VS 2015, Win32 project

MyLib.h

```
    #pragma once
#include <conio.h>


extern "C"
{
     __declspec(dllexport) extern int __stdcall get_key(int a);
}
```

MyLib.cpp

```
       #include "stdafx.h"

#include "MyLib.h"

extern "C" {
    _declspec(dllexport) extern int __stdcall get_key(int a)
    {
        int c = 0;

            if (_kbhit()) {
                c = _getch();
                return(c);
            }
        a = c;
        return c;
    }
}
```

And this, on build generates MyLib.dll and MyLib.lib
But when I try to import in in masm:

```
includelib MyLib.lib
get_key PROTO C,: DWORD
.data
doamne_ajuta dd 0
```

...

```
 push eax
    invoke get_key, doamne_ajuta
```

I have the following error: 
example.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _get_key referenced in function _draw@0
example.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: The assembly code doesn't know that this is an stdcall.  So it looks for the wrong identifier, `_get_key` instead of `_get_key@0`.  Either extend PROTO or drop stdcall.

Comment: you need declare in asm `extern __imp__get_key@4:proc` for x86 and `extern __imp_get_key:proc` for x64